# Upload file from localStorage using JS

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to download a file from a URL and then store it in localStorage, then post it to an end point.

```
<script>
        var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

        xhr.open('GET',
            'https://maxcdn.icons8.com/Share/icon/Logos//google_logo1600.png',
            true);
        xhr.responseType = "blob";
        xhr.onload = function(e){ //Stringify blob...
            //reload the icon from storage
            var fr = new FileReader();
            fr.onload =
                function(e) {
                    localStorage['icon'] = e.target.result;
                   sendFile();
                };
            fr.readAsDataURL(xhr.response);
        };
        xhr.send(null);


        function sendFile(){
            var form = document.createElement('form');
            form.setAttribute('method', 'post');
            form.setAttribute('action', 'http://posttestserver.com/post.php');
            form.setAttribute('enctype', 'multipart/form-data');

            var payload = {'uploadfield': localStorage['icon']};

            var hiddenField = document.createElement("input");
            hiddenField.setAttribute("type", "file");
            hiddenField.setAttribute("name", 'uploadfield');
            hiddenField.setAttribute("value", payload.uploadfield);
            form.appendChild(hiddenField);

            document.body.appendChild(form);
            form.submit();
        }
    </script>
```

Here is how I do it. But it seems the file is not uploaded/posted. Is there a better way to do it? Basically, I'm trying to download a file upon page load and then post the file to an endpoint.

Comment: Why not just send the `e.target.result` as an argument to the new `sendFile(iconResult)` function? Is there a reason why you want to use localStorage for this?

Comment: It's still not posting the file. No reason to use localStorage. Just wanted to post the file. Was just experimenting with localStorage

Comment: localstorage is the wrong place to store blobs, use IndexedDB for that...

Answer (score 0):

There is one flaw in your way of doing it.
You can't set the value of any input type which value is `file`
(appart from empty value `""` which clear the input field)

And if it would work you would not definitely not set the value to a base64 string, It would have to be a [File](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/File) Object

Here is some tracking issue:

https://github.com/w3c/FileAPI/issues/19
https://github.com/w3c/FileAPI/issues/24

---

**Now to solve this** you would have to submit a [FormData](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData/FormData) and using Ajax

Here is a es5 version:

```js
fetch('https://maxcdn.icons8.com/Share/icon/Logos//google_logo1600.png')
.then(function(res){
  return res.blob()
})
.then(sendfile)

function sendFile(blob){
  var fd = new FormData()
  fd.append('uploadfield', blob, 'filename.png')

  return fetch('http://posttestserver.com/post.php', {
    method: 'post',
    body: fd
  })
  .then(function(res){
    return res.text()
  })
  .then(function(text){
    // response from a successful upload
    // location.href = new page
  })
}
```

And a es6

```js
fetch('https://maxcdn.icons8.com/Share/icon/Logos//google_logo1600.png')
  .then(res => res.blob())
  .then(sendfile)
  
function sendFile(blob){
  const fd = new FormData()
  fd.append('uploadfield', blob, 'filename.png')

  return fetch('http://posttestserver.com/post.php', {
    method: 'post',
    body: fd
  })
  .then(res => res.text())
  .then(text => {
    // response from a successful upload
    // location.href = new page
  })
}
```

---

And if you would want to store the blob on the client side use [IndexedDB](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/IndexedDB_API) Api, it can store blobs better